# MomentJS checking isBefore without day

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have been using momentJS to detect the future date without day. Here is my code and result:

```
moment('09/2010').isBefore(moment().format('MM/YYYY'), 'day')
```

I'm getting result as `false`. But I'm supposed to get `true`. Is I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `"09/2010"` is not a valid date format, is it? What is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input (`'09/2010'`) is not in recognized format (ISO 8601 or RFC 2822) so you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

You can use [`startOf('month')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to get a moment object for the start of the current month.

```js
console.log( moment('09/2010', 'MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment().startOf('month'), 'day')) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **`moment('09/2010')`** without format it doesn't make sense. you have to provide a **format** for this date like **`moment('09/2010', 'MM/YYYY')`**.
You should see below code:

```
if(moment('09/2010', 'MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment().startOf('month'),'day')){
    /* 
     * Do something here
     */ 
    return true;

}else{
      /* 
       * Do something here
       */

    return false;
}
```

**You can use below code for understanding:**

```
if (moment('09/2010','MM/YYYY').isBefore('10/2010','MM/YYYY')) {
                      /* 
                       * Do something here
                       */ 

                    return true;
   }else{
                      /* 
                       * Do something here
                       */

                    return false;
        }
```

Hope it will help you.